# Doubt in a step in a proof

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to G$ a rectifiable path. In a step in a proof it is stated that since $\{\gamma\}$ is a compact set (the braces denote the image set of $\gamma$) then
$$
dist(\{\gamma\},\partial G)>0
$$
where the distance between sets is defined by
$$
dist(A,B)=inf(d(a,b)\, |\, a \in A, b\in B)
$$
why does compactness of $\{\gamma\}$ imply the distance being bigger than zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The def'n of rectifiable path, whatever it is in your source, implies that $\{\gamma\}$ is compact.

Let $A$ be a non-empty compact subset of the open set $B. $  For every $x\in A$ there is an open ball $B(x,r_x)$ of radius $r_x>0$ such that $B\supset B(x,r_x).$

Now $\{B(x,r_x/2):x\in A\}$ is an open cover of $A, $ so there exists a non-empty finite $A^*\subset A$ such that $\{B(x,r_x/2):x\in A^*\}$ covers $A$  (because $A$ is compact).  Let $s=\min \{r_x/2: x\in A^*\}.$ Then $s>0. $

For any $y\in A$ we have $y\in B(x,r_x/2) $ for some $x\in A^*.$ Since $y\in B(x,r_x/2)\subset B(x,r_x)\subset B, $ the distance from  $y$ to any point in $ \overline { \mathbb C \backslash B}$ is at least $x_r/2, $ which is at least $s.$

Answer (score 1):

Because the distance between disjoint sets, one of which is closed and the other compact, is positive. Since the boundary of $G$ is closed, your statement follows.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed set, the distance from it is a continuous function. If the set is closed, the distance is positive for each point not contained in it. A continuous function on a compact set has a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of $\{\gamma\}$ and  $\partial G$ is  trivial, since the image of $\gamma$ is contained in $G$.
  There exists $(x_n), x_n\in \{\gamma\}$ $(y_n\in \partial G)$ such that $lim_nd(x_n,y_n)=d(\{\gamma\},\partial G)$. Since $\{\gamma\}$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $(x_{f(n)}$ of $(x_n)$ which converges towards $x\in\{\gamma\}$, this implies that $lim_n d(x,y_{f(n)}))=lim_nd(x_{f(n)},y_{f(n)})=d(\{\gamma\},G)=d(x,G)$. Suppose $d(\{\gamma\},G)=0$. We deduce that $lim_nd(x,y_{f(n)})=0$, since $\partial G$ is closed, $x\in \partial G$, contradiction.

Comment: Noe that, in the context of this question, we know that the intersection of $\{\gamma\}$ and $\partial G$ is empty, because $\{\gamma\}\subseteq G$ and $G$ is open.